# При прослушивании стримов SSE идут undefined события

Tags: node.js, sse

Вопрос может быть очень глупый. Но почему-то событие EventSource почти в половине случаев генерирует событие undefined. Если слушать лишь первый стрим (recentchanges), то такого нет. Если только второй, изредка проскакивает. А вот если оба (recentchanges,revisioncreate), то почти половина. Что это означает и что с этим делать?

```
var url = 'https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange,revision-create';

var source = new EventSource(url);
source.onmessage = function(e) {
    if (e.type !== "message") return;
    if (!e.hasOwnProperty("data")) // отлавливаем ошибку
        console.log(e); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете вместо этого:

```
    if (!e.hasOwnProperty("data"))
```

Написать так:

```
if (!e?.data)
```

Я думаю, что здесь вы найдете ответ на вопрос: https://learn.javascript.ru/server-sent-events